# Slide from left (or right) animation transaction for UIView

Tags: objective-c, ios5, uiview, uiviewanimation

I want to do a slide from left (or right) animation with my UIView like how it is done in Photos.app while you browse thorough photos by swiping left and right.

I know the following basic animation transaction code.

```
[UIView beginAnimations:@"ThisAnimation" context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:1];
[UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionCurlUp forView:self.view cache:YES];    

[UIView commitAnimations];
```

Is it possible to do slide from left (or right) animation using setAnimationTransaction? If not, how can I do it?

Comment: If you want to replicate the Photos app's behavior you might want to use a UIScrollView with `scrollView.pagingEnabled = YES` instead. This way you'll get instant feedback once you start dragging the image. Using transition will require the user to finish a whole swipe gesture before the transition can be triggered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to the other answer, you can [find a cool tutorial here](http://sugartin.info/2012/01/21/image-sliding-page-by-page-uiscrollview-auto-scrolling-like-image-slider/) and there is a link to the project at the end of the tutorial so you can take a look at it.

This is an automatic slideshow, but you can disable it by commenting the line where the `NSTimer` is defined. Also you should had the next line in the `viewDidLoad` for a better UX :

```
scr.pagingEnabled = YES;
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're after is a scroll view with paging enabled to be the main view that contains subviews for each of your photos. With paging enabled (the default value for this boolean property is `NO`), the view will always "snap" to a multiple of its bounds, so the user is always either on one section of the scroll view or another (like in Photos, or on the Home screen).

You can set the `pagingEnabled` property of the `UIScrollView` to be true to gain this effect. You will then always have multiples of the bounds of the `UIScrollView` shown at a time (which you could fill with a view for a photo, such as a `UIImageView`).

Answer (score 0):

In your swipe handlers write following code for your view:

```
let transition = CATransition()
transition.type = CATransitionType.push

transition.subtype = CATransitionSubtype.fromRight //In Left  swipe method

transition.subtype = CATransitionSubtype.fromLeft //In Right  swipe method

self.view.layer.add(transition, forKey: nil)
```